# SQL UPDATE with composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-update, composite-primary-key

How can I update with a composite primary key ?

ex:

```
UPDATE TABLE X 
SET FIELD_1 = 'blabla' , FIELD_2 = 'blabla' ,FIELD_3 = 'blabla'
WHERE FIELD_1 = 'HH' AND FIELD_2 = 'GG'
```

`FIELD_1` AND `FIELD_2` are the columns making up the primary key.

**see image-->**[UPDATE...](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stevchen99/6217506088/)

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've shown here?

Comment: it not work as you can see in image

Comment: I can't see anything in that picture. Please copy and paste the error message as text into your question.

Comment: All the picture shows is that no rows were updated, which does not necesarelly indicate the update being wrong. However, the statement you have there sets `Zone = @Zone WHERE Zone = @Zone`, which is a No-Op and not what you describe above.

Comment: The fact that you have a composite key doesn't change the way `where` clauses work. So probably you just don't have rows matching the `where` clause, or the update doesn't change the row.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: It might of course result in an error if you try updating it to an existing key, though.

Comment: @inflagranti But that is the same thing as updating a non-composite key. I am trying to point out that the "compositeness" of the key doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: That's true.

Comment: Thanks you all, i have change it SET  `[ZONE] = @ZONE ... WHERE [ZONE] = @OldZone` ...Now it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image you have:

```
SET ZONE = @ZONE...
....
WHERE ZONE = @ZONE
```

You cannot search for an item with the new value you want to set it to.

Use the old value in the `WHERE`

```
SET ZONE = @NEW_ZONE...
....
WHERE ZONE = @OLD_ZONE
```

The same applies to the other fields in your query.